# What is spacy spangroup. When and How do we use it? Will it help in overlapping spans?

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3, spacy-transformers

I've used the code below to create spans using spacy.

```
from collections import Counter
from spacy.tokens import DocBin


def make_spans(lst):
    """
    Split list of numbers into a list of (start,end) tuples,
    e.g. [1,2,3,4,10,11,12] of indexes becomes [(1,5), (10,13)] (exclusive end index)
    """
    start = None
    spans = []
    last_d = None
    for d in lst:
        if last_d is None:
            start = d
        elif d > last_d + 1:
            spans.append( (start, last_d + 1) )
            start = d
        last_d = d
    if start is not None:
        spans.append( (start, last_d + 1) )
    return spans

  
  def read_data(fname: str):
    """
    Read data from CSV file with rows (list(indexes), text)
    :param fname: (relative) path of file with CSV data
    """
    with open(fname, newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        _ = next(reader)  # skip the headers
        for row in reader:
            lst = ast.literal_eval(row[0])
            text = row[1]
            yield lst, text
            
 
def create_docbin(fname: str, basename: str, nlp, span_label='toxic_spans'):
    """Create a DocBin from a CSV with data rows (list(indexes), text)
    For each row:
    - define a `Doc` object from the `text`
    - create `Span` objects with the label 'TOXIC' based on the indexes from the CSV
    - add these Span objects to the doc's entities and those to the doc's spans
    - add the created doc to the `DocBin` object
    """
    doc_bin = DocBin()
    for spans, text in read_data(fname):
        ms = make_spans(spans)
        doc = nlp(text)
        span_lst = []
        for start, end in ms:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label='TOXIC')
            if span is not None:
                span_lst.append(span)
        # span_lst is now a list of spaCy `Span` objects
        # Set the Spans as document entities
        doc.set_ents(span_lst)
        # Set the document entities as spans
        doc.spans[span_label] = list(doc.ents)
        doc_bin.add(doc)
    # Save to totality of created documents with their spans in the custom binary `spacy` format  
    doc_bin.to_disk(f'corpus/{basename}.spacy')
```

I'm unable to use overlapping spans and it gives me an error when I've 2 labels which is  food and ingredient. Food span has longer text while ingredient is just a single word. How can I resolve this? And will Spangroup help in this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

A SpanGroup is basically just a list of Spans - there's a little more to it, but not much. You really shouldn't have to think about the SpanGroups in particular.

Entities on a Doc are specifically defined as a list of **non-overlapping** spans. If you need overlapping spans, then yes, you can save them in a SpanGroup, which is exactly what your code is already doing - when you assign a list to `doc.spans[something]`, it's converted into a SpanGroup automatically.

If you want to train a model to predict spans like that, you'll need to use a spancat component. You can read more about that in [the spancat blogpost](https://explosion.ai/blog/spancat).

Comment: Please can you share code for the implementation of spangroup for the above code? ALso, I'm getting an error if I try to have more than 2 labels on a the entity. How can i tackle that?

Comment: Just remove the line with `doc.set_ents` and change the next line to `doc.spans[span_label] = span_lst`. Then `doc.spans[span_label]` will be a SpanGroup. You don't need to explicitly use a SpanGroup.

Comment: How can I explicitly mention SpanGroup in the above code?